# Looping ggplot with subset

Tags: r, ggplot2

Looking to create a subset of my data based on the unique names in a column (Congener) and loop a ggplot that is saved with a specific name into my working directory.

What this code is doing is constructing a plot and outputting the subset names, however the data itself isn't subsetted into the unique name. Also there are columns (threshold, CHMS, Weber) that have values that I want to create a horizontal line for. Not all the unique names have a CHMS or Weber value, but hoping that doesn't affect the code.

Why is the data not being subsetted? Can I also loop this for all combinations of 4 different columns (for instance, I have columns Congener, Age, Gender, Ethnicity)?

```r
# load ggplot2
library(ggplot2)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr) # for data manipulation

#set wd to location where plots will be saved
setwd('')

#getting all the congeners that will be looped over

congener_list = unique(dt$Congener)

#Creating an empty list to save plots crated. Lists in R are very versatile.
#They can pretty much store any type of data in them
quantile_plots = list()

#looping over unique congener names
for (i in congener_list) {
    dt %>% filter(Congener == i) %>%
    
    quantile_plots[[i]] = ggplot(aes(x = Dataset, y = y, color = Type)) +
         labs(y = 'ng/g Lipid Weight') +
         ggtitle(congener_list[i]) +
         scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log10')+
         geom_jitter(
            data = dt,
            shape = 19,
            alpha = 0.5,
            size = 4
            ) 
            
    quantile_plots[[i]] +
         geom_hline(aes(yintercept= threshold), color = 'red', size = 1.2) +
         geom_hline(aes(yintercept= CHMS), color = 'orange') +
         geom_hline(aes(yintercept= Weber), color = 'pink', size = 1.2)
         
    print(quantile_plots[[i]])
    
    #save the plots to disk
    ggsave(quantile_plots[[i]], file=paste0('Quantile_plot_', i, '.png'),
    width = 44.45, height = 27.78, units = 'cm', dpi = 600)
}
```

The ideal output is here. What currently happens is that the title and name are correct, but the jittered data is all the data and not a specific subset. [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tA14.png)

Comment: the dt in the geom_jitter is the original dt, unflitered. Are you sure that facets would not do what you want?

Comment: Does this code generate any errors? If so, please post. Or does code work but with undesired results?

Comment: @Parfait Currently it gives this error, Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class uneval.
Did you accidentally pass `aes()` to the `data` argument?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
-1

Comment: @RichardTelford it does not post the right image currently. It has all the data jittered and not just the unique name

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your `ggplot` to assign the entire piped object to list which you can do with reverse assignment `->` after or before with `<-`. Also, remove the data argument so [**`geom_jitter`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/0.9.0/topics/geom_jitter) inherits subsetted data from plot:

Assign After:

```r
dt %>% filter(Congener == i) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Dataset, y = y, color = Type)) +
         labs(y = 'ng/g Lipid Weight') +
         ggtitle(congener_list[i]) +
         scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log10') +
         geom_jitter(
            shape = 19,
            alpha = 0.5,
            size = 4
         ) -> quantile_plots[[i]]
```

Assign Before:

```r
quantile_plots[[i]] <- dt %>% 
    filter(Congener == i) %>%
    ggplot(...) +
    ...
```

---

However, consider `by` to slice your data frame by various factors and then run a generialized plot function:

**Build Plot Function**

*`tryCatch` added to catch errors on problematic runs, print message and return `NULL` to not interrupt loop*

```r
build_plot <- function(sub_df) {
  tryCatch({
    group_title <- with(
        sub_df, 
        paste(Congener[1], Age[1], Gender[1], Ethnicity[1], sep = "_")
    )

    plt <- sub_df %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = Dataset, y = y, color = Type)) +
            labs(y = 'ng/g Lipid Weight') +
            ggtitle(group_title) +
            scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log10') +
            geom_jitter(
                shape = 19, alpha = 0.5, size = 4
            ) 
            
    # CONDITIONALLY ADD HLINES IF COLUMNS EXIST
    if("intercept" %in% names(sub_df)) {
        plt <- plt + geom_hline(aes(yintercept= threshold), color = 'red', size = 1.2)
    }
    if("CHMS" %in% names(sub_df)) {
        plt <- plt + geom_hline(aes(yintercept= CHMS), color = 'orange')
    }
    if("Weber" %in% names(sub_df)) {
        plt <- plt + geom_hline(aes(yintercept= Weber), color = 'pink', size = 1.2)
    }
    
    # print plot in console
    print(plt)
    
    # save plot to disk
    ggsave(
        plt, file = paste0(group_title, ".png"), width = 44.45, height = 27.78, units = 'cm', dpi = 600
    )

    return(plt)
  }, error = function(e) { print(e); return(NULL) }
  )
}
```

**By Group(s) Call**

*Adjust `group_title` in function depending on which group you run*

```r
# ONE GROUP
quantile_plots <- by(dt, dt$Congener, build_plot)

# TWO GROUPS
quantile_plots <- by(dt, dt[c("Congener", "Age")], build_plot)

# THREE GROUPS
quantile_plots <- by(dt, dt[c("Congener", "Age", "Gender")], build_plot)

# FOUR GROUPS
quantile_plots <- by(dt, dt[c("Congener", "Age", "Gender", "Ethnicity")], build_plot)
```

Comment: It returns a list of zero items in this code for plt. Wondering if there is something missing here. Are the ggplots not being generated and added to the list?

Comment: Please delete comments with hard to read code (especially if repeating this solution). For `by` (and all apply methods) you do need the bookkeeping need of initializing object with `plot <- list()`. Are there any printed error messages? Is `plt` empty after calling `by` or does it contain `NULL` elements? Do plots not save to disk? Check working directory. I may need `dput` of your data.